# How to remove "public" from the root directory access link?

Tags: redirect, cpanel, web-hosting

i'am new to the hosting/c-panel stuff, and i got a laravel based app installed on my godaddy hosting, the problem is that the application require some files that are placed on the root directory of the server for example `http://server.com/images/ajax-loader.gif` and the file is placed just there
[image: image directory]

but when i type the link `http://server.com/images/ajax-loader.gif` it doesn't find it:
[image: error 404]

so i need to add a public like `http://server.com/public/images/ajax-loader.gif` like:
[image: image found]

the problem is that the entire app needs to be modified to add a public for every file like that, so is there any way i can access the root folder without adding this **/public/** ?

Comment: Is it your main domain on this cPanel account? Typically (at least for my account) a document root for the main domain is `/public_html`. You can check it via Domains > Domains on cPanel. So if I put `images/ajax-loader.gif` inside `/public_html`, I would able to get the image using `http://my-server.com/images/ajax-loader.gif` (without any `/public_html` part).

Answer (score 0):

Have you contacted the hosting provider? Usually, they help with these kinds of issues.

Do other images from your 'images' directory load fine? If all images in the images directory do not load in the browser, that indicates either a permission issue or some .htaccess settings. Again needs to be checked at the hosting provider end.